# Python multiple process share the same object or not?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I found this [why multiple processes have the same object id in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817442/why-multiple-processes-have-the-same-object-id-in-python), but I do not quite understand what does it mean "because both processes execute the same code", I try the code, it seems the outputs are always the same.

`➜  ~ python test2.py
4419085696
4419085696
➜  ~ python test2.py
4342830464
4342830464
➜  ~ python test2.py
4510156160
4510156160
➜  ~ python test2.py
4329948544
4329948544
➜  ~ python test2.py
4468004224
4468004224
➜  ~ python test2.py
4326647168
4326647168
➜  ~ python test2.py
4445738368
4445738368
➜  ~ python test2.py
4388980096
4388980096
➜  ~ python test2.py
4511999360
4511999360
➜  ~ python test2.py
4562851200
4562851200
➜  ~ python test2.py
4535031168
4535031168
➜  ~ python test2.py
4314420608
4314420608
➜  ~ python test2.py
4536034688
4536034688`

I also find this refer http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/656748/ on web. It also seems that python multiple processes shares the same object.

Anyone could help to explain a bit further? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS do you run on?

Comment: I am using Mac OS, I think two process should have two virtual address space as well, but I confused when I run the code in the two links. The program produce two processes, I thought the each process should have its own copy of the object, rather than use the same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `id` of an object in CPython is the objects memory address *as seen by the process itself*. The OS prevents different processes from seeing other processes memory.

*Gross simplification warning* As far as each process is concerned, its memory space starts at 0 and goes up. Two different processes that start up and ask for a 1000-byte block of memory from the OS will both think they have memory block 0-1000, but they are not actually sharing memory.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space for a good intro and better explanation.

Comment: Thank your for your answer, I think each process has their own memory as well. But when I run the python code in the above two links, the program produces two process, and try to manage the same object, it seems both process deal with the same objects. I am really confuse about this, since I think each process should copy the objects to their own memory space, and deal with two different objects.

Comment: I think twice, you mean the ID  of an object maybe seem the same in multiple processes, but they are different and isolated objects by the OS. right?

Comment: Yes, just because the id of the object is the same in *two different python processes", does not mean they are the same object. Processes do not/cannot share memory unless you set up a special shared memory area specifically for that purpose, which I assume you are not doing.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try some python code to test this.