# Python multiprocessing que is duplicated

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm creating sub-processes as `worker` objects that get and return data through `input` and `output` queues.
However, when code is run, it seems that each subprocess obtains complete copy of the `input` queue and main thread does not get anything through `output` queue, which is causing deadlock. Why is that?

```
import threading, queue, multiprocessing
class worker(multiprocessing.Process):
     def __init__(self,inp,out):
         super().__init__()
         self.input=inp
         self.output=out
         #real program has external subprocess initialization here
     def run(self):
         name=self.name
         while True:
             inp=self.input.get()
             if (inp is 'stop'):
                 break
             print('Process {} got task word: {}'.format(name,inp))
             print('queue size is: {}'.format(self.input.qsize()))
             self.output.put(inp.count('a'))
             print('Process {} input processed'.format(name))
         print('exiting {}'.format(name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inp=queue.Queue()
    out=queue.Queue(maxsize=4)
    strings = ['asd', 'assa','aaa','as','aa','aaaq']
    for x in strings:
        inp.put(x)
    print(inp.qsize())
    workers=[worker(inp,out) for x in range(2)]
    for w in workers:
        w.start()
    res=[]
    for x in strings:
        res.append(out.get())
        print("intermediate result is {}".format(res))
    for _ in workers:
        inp.put('stop')
    for w in workers:
        w.join()

    print(res)
```

In the real problem each worker would initialize its own interface to another external program. I want to avoid repeating that initialization per each item, so I cannot simply convert worker to a function and use it with `map`.

If `multiprocessing.Process` is replaced with `threading.Thread` which has the same api, the program works correctly, but on single core which is unacceptable for the task.

Comment: The code in your main will run on after you start the works until you call w.join() . So you collect the output too early.

Depending on your processor / systems the works might or might not have started their work yet when you get the output. There is also something else wrong, but I do not have the means to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different processes do not share processes memory so you cannot share the queue between different processes. Each process gets its own copy.

[Python multiple process share the same object or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977765/python-multiple-process-share-the-same-object-or-not)

You have to use IPC mechanisms  for synchronizing multiple processes.

However, threads share the process memory so it will work for threads but not for processes.

### Solution for mutiprocess

Use mutliprocessing Queues

```
import threading, multiprocessing
class worker(multiprocessing.Process):
     def __init__(self,inp,out):
         super().__init__()
         self.input=inp
         self.output=out
         #real program has external subprocess initialization here
     def run(self):
         name=self.name
         while True:
             inp=self.input.get()
             if (inp == 'stop'):
                 break
             print('Process {} got task word: {}'.format(name,inp))
             #print('queue size is: {}'.format(self.input.qsize()))
             self.output.put((inp, inp.count('a')))
             print('Process {} input processed'.format(name))
         print('exiting {}'.format(name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inp=multiprocessing.Queue()
    out=multiprocessing.Queue()
    strings = ['asd', 'assa','aaa','as','aa','aaaq']
    for x in strings:
        inp.put(x)

    workers=[worker(inp,out) for x in range(2)]
    for w in workers:
        w.start()

    for _ in workers:
        inp.put('stop')
    #print (inp.qsize())


    inp.close()
    inp.join_thread()

    for w in workers:
        w.join()

    print (out.empty())
    while not out.empty():
        print (out.get())
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize that `queue.Queue` does not provide right queues for the processes. Changing the order of reading from queue and joining workers was unneeded however. The whole idea behind using queues was to have worker that outlives both input and output (those can be large and are not needed simultaneously)

Comment: @Dimitry yes it is no necessary to change the order,  I was just trying out some stuff and did not change it back. Glad it helped :)